# Two's complement max with a different base

Tags: number-theory, number-formats

Working with fixed size integer representations,
use a number system with b-complement notation, base b = 9 and
n = 4 digits.
 What is the smallest number that can be represented in this number system?
State the number in decimal, and also express it in this number
system.
I assume that it will be 0888 for max, and 8000 for min. If I am right, then what is the max number of integers that I can represent using this notation.

Comment: If you can calculate this for binary, you should be able to calculate this for any other base.

Comment: I am not sure about the first digit, whether it is always 0 for positive and n-1 (in the context of base n) for negative, or it increases until some point.

Comment: It's up to you – arithmetic will work whatever convention you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as different 4 digit numbers in base b represent different decimal numbers, the particular notation one uses is not relevant to see how many integers can be represented. I'm not sure how the two-complement notation generalizes to the b-complement notation, but if the above property holds, then clearly there will be 9^4 representable integers.

My guess is that the first digit does not need to be 0 or 8, it can be any digit. That is, I think one could use the following encoding:

0000 0
...
4444 MAX
4445 MIN = -MAX
4446 MIN+1
...
8888 -1